# #AskFirebase Firestore - Prevent fetching entire collection without specific query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection of students. Every student has a name and classId.
My requirements are:

- You **can** fetch a student data and see on which class he is (fetch by
  id).
- You **can** fetch all the students of a class (query by classId).
- You **can't** list the students collection without classId filter.
- a "Manager" can list the entire students collection and filter students by name\classId

Can this be achieved using security rules?

Comment: what is id ? class id? how you are going to distinguish mgr?

Comment: but whatever! you can achieve all this by putting rules :)

Comment: Yes.  You can achieve this

Comment: The id is the studentId. Can u guys please show a sample? I read the rules section, but couldn't find a way to fail the rule based on the query itself, only based on the documents data. I thought it was the request.resource, but this seems like only for writing.

Comment: @rijin & Jason if you guys know a way. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Apparently the guidelines don't elaborate on this, but in the [request.query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#query) reference it does:</strike>

```
// Allow a query if the user is requesting less than or equal to 10 items
allow list: if request.query.limit <= 10;

// Allow a query starting at the 10th item
allow list: if request.query.offset == 10;

// Allow a query if it's grouped by user (e.g. user anonyous queries)
allow list: if request.query.groupBy['user'] == true;

// Only allow ascending queries on timestamps
allow list: if request.query.orderBy['timestamp'] == 'ASC';
```

**EDIT**

So the above didn't work for me and I contacted google, and they say that the query functionality is not supported, and that they need to remove it from the docs.

**EDIT again**
So I finally came up with a solution that satisfies me for now. It's not perfect thought, but it solves the problem.
I added a "dummy student" to the collection with no classId and I added a rule as follows:

```
match /students/{studentId} {
  allow get;
  allow list: if resource.data.keys().hasAny(['classId']);
}
```

Now all the rules above are met, but a new problem was created. When the manager tries to query the entire collection, he might run into this dummy student.
I couldn't find a good way to solve this, so what I had to do, is also add a dummy field ({a: true}) on all students except for the dummy one, and when the manager queries the data, I also add a where clause `where('a', '==', true)`. This solves my problem but it's kind of an ugly solution. If someone has a better solution, I'd be happy to hear it.